# Why I am repeatedly getting this error whenever I try to use ie.attach command?

Tags: syntax-error, g1ant

[image]Error picture
I even tried while keeping Internet Explorer running in the background

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing " by title" phrase and then try